# Cannot stream webcam using ffserver because of malloc error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I was following this tutorial [RaspBerry Pi webcam](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.com/2012/05/raspberry-pi-webcam.html) and when I run the following command from root:

```
$ ffserver -f /root/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v 2 -r 5 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1` http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm
```

The camera is turned on and everything is fine, except it does not stream. I checked the terminal. From video 1, I get the following error:

```
bind(port 8090): Address already in use
*** glibc detected *** ffmpeg: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000000e5ac00 **
```

When I use another port like 5000, I get the same result:

```
$ ffserver -f /root/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v 2 -r 5 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm
[2] 3795
avserver version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:52:09 with gcc 4.6.3
*** glibc detected *** ffmpeg: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000000b77c00 ***
```

Comment: i got to localhost and it says this feed is already being received and the link from the tutorial never open.

Comment: Did you build anything from source, or are these all maintainer-supplied packages? In the latter case, file a bug report.